# Static and instance method with same name?

Tags: java, arguments

I have created two methods name sum
one sum method is an instance method this method only takes `int ...nums` and another sum method is
static method it's takes `int x` and `int ...nums`.

My code

```
public class varArgs{
    int sum(int ...nums){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int num: nums){
            sum += num;
            }
        return sum;
        }
    static int sum(int x, int ...nums){
        int sum = x;
        for (int num: nums){
            sum += num;
            }
         return sum;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        varArgs obj = new varArgs();
        System.out.println("3 + 4 = "+ obj.sum(3,4));
        System.out.println("7 + 3 + 4 = "+ obj.sum(7, 8,9));
        System.out.println("10 +1+5+6+7= "+obj.sum(10,1,5,6,7));
        System.out.println(obj.sum());
        
        System.out.println(sum(7, 8, 9, 10));
        
        
    }
}
```

The error I am getting

```
/storage/emulated/0/varArgs.java:18: error: reference to sum is ambiguous
        System.out.println("3 + 4 = "+ obj.sum(3,4));
                                          ^
  both method sum(int...) in varArgs and method sum(int,int...) in varArgs match
/storage/emulated/0/varArgs.java:19: error: reference to sum is ambiguous
        System.out.println("7 + 3 + 4 = "+ obj.sum(7, 8,9));
                                              ^
  both method sum(int...) in varArgs and method sum(int,int...) in varArgs match
/storage/emulated/0/varArgs.java:20: error: reference to sum is ambiguous
        System.out.println("10 +1+5+6+7= "+obj.sum(10,1,5,6,7));
                                              ^
  both method sum(int...) in varArgs and method sum(int,int...) in varArgs match
/storage/emulated/0/varArgs.java:23: error: reference to sum is ambiguous
        System.out.println(sum(7, 8, 9, 10));
                           ^
  both method sum(int...) in varArgs and method sum(int,int...) in varArgs match
4 errors
```

How can I solve this Error

Comment: You don't need the second method. Remove it. And you can make the first one static.

Comment: `obj.sum(yourValues)` -- You do not need to create an object to call a static method, you can just do `sum(yourValues)` directly.  There is no reason to convert this to non-static either as the method is unrelated to the state of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first non-static method and leave this one, you can add the initial number into the other numbers being added

```java
public static int add(int ... nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int num : nums) {
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

BTW make sure to make your class names start with an uppercase (VarArgs, not varArgs)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `int ...nums` parameter. It avoids creating the array explicitly.

Comment: I never realized you could do that in a method, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your **non-static method** and try to using correct name conversion.

```
static int sum(int x, int ...nums){
    int sum = x;
    for (int num: nums){
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

[ClassName]  obj = new [ClassName]  ();

System.out.println("3 + 4 = "+ obj.sum(3,4));

```
 System.out.println("7 + 3 + 4 = "+ obj.sum(7, 8,9));
```

System.out.println("10 +1+5+6+7= "+obj.sum(10,1,5,6,7));
`System.out.println(obj.sum())`;

> // hope you using values inside the sum() method because you created
> parameterized method.

```
 System.out.println(sum(7, 8, 9, 10));
```

}